# What exactly did they show to the big audience in "Windy City Heat"?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, windy-city-heat

The whole thing with [*Windy City Heat*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windy_City_Heat) (2003) is that it's supposed to be an "elaborate prank" on this unknowing guy, Perry. Of course, he isn't *actually* clueless, but plays dumb for comedy as part of this comedic trio.

And of course, there isn't an actual *Windy City Heat* movie that you can actually watch. It exists only as the scenes featured in the movie *Windy City Heat*, which is a behind-the-scenes documentary in style and not the "actual movie".

(Either that, or I'm completely fooled.)

But toward the very end, when they finally get to the huge audience waiting for them and meeting the "President of Show Business" and getting the big trophy and all that, it really seems to me as if they have shown some kind of movie to the audience due to their facial expressions. But what could they show when there is no actual *Windy City Heat* movie, and the documentary-style one they are currently shooting is not finished yet?

Or was that entire audience really made up by paid actors? It seems to me like they couldn't afford that. The people look famous too. Did they just get all those people to play along on their prank after/before some actual (paid for by somebody else entirely) happening to which all those people were invited?

Answer (score 2):

This movie was produced by Jimmy Kimmel and Adam Carolla. Jimmy is famous for his deeply involved long form pranks. Carolla has said on multiple occasions that Perry had no idea this was a prank [Don Barris himself on IMDB asserts this was true and that Perry had no idea.](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw0933529/?ref_=tt_urv) Barris goes on to suggest that they had more in mind for the prank which is why there is no reveal. For example they go on Jimmy Kimmel Live as real guests with a movie coming out ands he seems to be still in the prank.

As for the movie premiere, they did shoot a lot of scenes and it is obvious that the ending of the fake movie had scenes that were shot. Presumably one of the reasons they made Perry late to the premiere was to carry on the ruse that they would only get there for the end of the movie and the audience would cheer wildly and the President of Show Business would award them the festival winner on the spot. The Theater was certainly filled with extras. The famous people you recognize include Carolla and Kimmel and maybe the friends of theirs.

The audience is faking having watched the whole movie but Perry doesn't know because they got to the premiere late (late limo, convenience store, girls dancing, limo driver driving past theater, bouncer not letting them in etc.) They probably only watched the last few minutes that we saw - they would know when the limo got there and started the end of the film as the big 3 walked in.